# Disable Swipe from UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, swipe

I have a UITabBarController in my iOS Swift application. I set the transition in main.storyboard to page curl. the page curl happens when the tabBarController view and embedded views are introduced which looks excellent, but then tapping or swiping anywhere near the top of the embedded views causes the entire UITabBarController to dismiss.

How do I remove this functionality within the embedded VCs?

I don't really have any code to reference in this case, but I'm hoping it's an easy fix. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a huge longstanding bug in the page curl presentation style. The best policy is not to use it.

Comment: thanks @matt. I changed the style and that removed the problem. is there any documentation on this? I was surprised that it would be a 'long standing bug' but I can't seem to find anything about it, and spent quite a bit of time trying to understand what was going on with no hits on google/stack.